# Logging into Azure Sql

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I created a user in our AD Connected  on-prem Active Directory. The user is synced up to AAD.

This user is now tied to our on-prem domain

I have added this user as the SQL Active Directory Admin

My issue is:

I cannot login to azure sql with this AD Admin via SSMS or sqlcmd

I receive the error, login failed, as if the password isn’t correct or something

My question is:
Can I login to Azure sql with an on-prem ad synced aad user account?

Does Azure sql tie to the AAD tenant domain only, regardless of we have an AD-Connect set up with our on-prem domain?

I need to login to sql with the ad admin account, to beable to add other aad users or groups as a sql dB user

I believe that creating the user in our Ad makes the azure sql not recognize it, since the azure sql is on the aad domain

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to follow the steps provided on the following resources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure / https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication

Comment: If that step-by-step procedure does not help, please share with us more information about the error(s) you are receiving.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: Looking forward to be of more help.

Comment: Sorry I thought I responded back some time ago. So I have completed all of those steps and read most of the related document. My issue is with the fact that the user account being used for the sql ad Admin, came from the on prem ad domain. AZURE sql is not part of that domain, but rather the azure as tenant domain correct? So is it possible to login to an azure sql server, using an account synced up from an on prem synced domain? Sorry getting a bit confused

Comment: Yes. you can. Add the user to you Azure SQL server. CREATE USER [alice@fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

Comment: Update: I was able to figure out the issue. Our aad is set up with MFA, therefor the Sql AD Admin user needed to be set up with MFA. In SSMS, I was able to login using the full username listed in AAD, rather then the username@domain listed in my on Prem AD, where I created the account. Sqlcmd does not support MFA ad authentication apparently.

Comment: sqlcmd supports Azure Active Directory authentication beginning with ODBC version 13.1, but to my knowledge it does not support MFA.

Comment: I am glad you made it work.

Comment: A New questions came out of this however. The original idea was to add my SqlAdmins aad group as sysadmins to the sql server/databases. I know you can add a security group as the SQL AD Admin. How would I login with mfa to SSMS, if my SQL AD admin is an aad group, and not a user? I have no password to represent the aad group

Comment: If the answer is you cannot, do you know of an azure sql query, that I can assign a user permissions like a sysadmin or alter any?

Comment: Any user belonging to that Azure AD group can login. You can test with SSMS

Comment: Ahh so it is adding every user in the aad group, as an admin user, not the aad group it’s self as the user. So I can pick any users in the aad group, and login SSMS... I was thinking the aad group would be the user, which made no sense, since there is no password or way to login for the initial  mfa setup.... thank you very much . I have learned a lot

Comment: Confirmed login with user inside aad group used for the sql AD Admin.. This user has alter any rights.. Thank you. Please mark as correct!

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo You should write up a compilation of your comments as an answer :) I suppose these situations always depend on the tooling supporting AAD login. If they only ask for username + pass then MFA/federation cannot work. If the tooling supports interactive login, then all of those will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure) Azure documentation to configure Azure Active Directory (AAD) and use it to access an Azure SQL Database. After configuring AAD, you just need to add an ADD group as Azure SQL Database admin and all user part of that group will be able to use MFA authentication. You can use SQL Server Management Studio to test it.

SQLCMD does not support MFA authentication.